# Lorentz Transformation - Intuitive way to determine when to use Inverse transformation

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, conventions

Any intuitive way to decide when to use Lorentz transformation and when to use its inverse relation?

For example: A particle is moving with respect to me with speed of 0.99C. If question is : *What would I measure if particle measures 2 sec in its frame?*

If I use Lorentz equation, answer I get is: 2*0.141 = 0.282s which is wrong. However,
If I use Inverse, answer I get is: 2/0.141= 14.18s, which is correct.

How do I know that I have apply inverse in this case?

Comment: If you are moving with velocity $v$ with respect to the particle, use the Lorentz transformation associated with $v$.   (Call it $L(v)$.)  The inverse of $L(v)$ is $L(-v)$.   So for $v>0$, use $L(v)$ if you are moving rightward and its inverse if you are moving leftward.  For measuring time intervals between two events on the particle's worldline, both $L(v)$ and its inverse will give you the same answer, which means that time dilation depends only on your speed, not which direction you're moving.

Comment: "... particle measures 2 sec in its frame ..." What does this mean? How can a particle *measure 2 seconds*?

Comment: @PhilipWood what I meant was if clock in particle frame shows 2 sec

Comment: I've based my answer on that assumption!

Comment: Can you show your work? It looks to me like you aren't using the Lorentz transformation, but are just multiplying or dividing by $γ$.

Answer (score 0):

To make sense of your example, let's assume that the particle is, in fact, a clock, and that it shows (event A) at time $T$, and, a little later, it shows (event B) a time of $(T+2\ \text s)$.

Suppose that we call the clock's rest frame 'S'. Then in S, event A occurs at position $x$ (say) and time $t=T$, while event B occurs at position $x$ and time $t=(T+2\ \text s)$.

Therefore in my frame, the S' frame moving with velocity $v=0.99\ c$ wrt the S frame,

Event A happens at $x'=\gamma (x-vT)$, $\ \ \ t'=\gamma (T-\frac v{c^2} x)$.

Event B happens at $x'=\gamma (x-v(T+2\ \text s))$, $\ \ \ t'=\gamma ((T+2\ \text s)-\frac v{c^2} x)$.

Clearly the the time difference between events A and B in my frame is $\Delta t'=\gamma \times 2\ \text s$.

[Here $\gamma= (1-0.99^2)^{-1/2}=7.1$]

We note that the events occur in different places in my frame, S'.

Now you could just as well call the clock's frame the S' frame. Then in S', event A occurs at position $x'$ (say) and time $t'=T$, while event B occurs at position $x'$ and time $t'=(T+2\ \text s)$.

If you use the inverse transform to get the time difference, $\Delta t$ in S, you'll get exactly the same result: 7.1 x 2 s.

If you've read this far you may think that the whole thing can be done more quickly without all this 'event A and event B' stuff. You'd be right, but if you think of the Lorentz transforms as linking space and time co-ordinates of **events**, you'll avoid many common confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Assume an observe O to be moving at speed $v$ w.r.t you and you measure the coordinates of an event then to find out coordinates in O frame, you have to use Lorentz Transformation and if the coordinates are  measured in frame of O then to get coordinates in your frame, you have to use inverse lorentz transformation, in this case as the time is recorded by moving frame so you have to multiply the time with $\gamma$ to get time in your frame. But one have to cautious because this is only valid if the two events(between which the time is measured by frame O) have happened at the same place in frame O. Else you have to apply inverse lorentz transformations correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use events:

$$ E_i = (t_i, x_i)_{\chi} $$

where $\chi$ refers to the frame. You have 2 events:

$$ E_0 = (0, 0)_{S'}$$
$$ E_1 = (2, 0)_{S'}$$

with

$$ \delta t' = 2-0 = 2 $$

Now transform these to $S$, which is "stationary". Since it's a moving frame to a stationary frame you go from primed to unprimed with an inverse LT. But that is just the convention of relativity problems. It doesn't matter which way we transform by $\beta$:

$$ E_0 = (0, 0)_S $$
$$ E_1 = \big(\gamma 2 + \beta 0, \gamma 0 + \beta 2)_S$$
$$ E_1 = (2\gamma, 2\beta)_S$$

so

$$\delta t = 2\gamma-0 = 2\gamma $$

et voila: your clock ran faster.

Note that events are invariant. They exist at a singular point in the Minkowski diagram, but are assigned different coordinate in different frames.

Answer (score 0):

The intuitive way is to identify the frame where there is only one clock.

In this case the expression "the particle is moving with respect to me" suggests only one clock in the frame of the particle. On the other hand, the expression "my frame" suggests not only my position but all the stuff that is static with respect to me. Any synchronized clock, no matter how far away, is also valid to measure "my time", if it does not move with respect to me.

The Lorentz transformation for the time is:
$$\Delta t' = \gamma \left (\Delta t - \frac{v\Delta x}{c^2}\right )$$
For the frame of only one clock, $\Delta x = 0$ because its position is always the same in its own frame. That way the Lorentz transformation becomes the time dilation formula:$\Delta t' = \gamma \Delta t$.

Note that it does not work if the prime coordinate is the particle frame, because the positions of the events are not the same in "my frame", so $\Delta x \neq 0$.